# Does requests.get() (Python, Requests module) pause a script until the response arrives?

Tags: python, python-requests

This question is regarding the Requests module for Python.

I'm using requests.get() and running into a problem where I exceed the rate limit of the requests the server I'm contacting allows me.  I have set a time.sleep() after each requests.get() to something that is an order of magnitude larger.  The code is like this:

```
        for url in url_list:
            success = False
            response = requests.get(url) 
            while not success:
                time.sleep(1/250)
                if str(response) == "<Response [200]>":
                    time.sleep(1/250) # Wait Xs between API call      
                    do_stuff(response.text)
                    success = True

                else:
                    print(response)
                    print(response.headers)
                    time.sleep(3)
                    response = requests.get(url)
```

I am constantly running up my rate here which is 300 requests / second, where as I should be sending only 125 requests per second at most.  Does Requests not pause the script until the response arrives?  I'm not sure.  How can I make sure I don't send more requests than my rate?

Comment: If it's python2 you are doing `time.sleep(0)`. Try `1./250`.

Comment: Are you sure that the only limit is 300/second (i.e., not also some daily limit), and are you sure that the failed requests are due to hitting that rate limit?

Comment: BrenBarn that's exactly what I'm trying to determine.   The only other limit I could be hitting is a variable "Server has too many requests so screw you" limit.  But in the case of an error I wait 3s which again should be plenty of time.

So I'm not sure if requests.get() pauses the script until a response is received, or what.

Comment: Interestingly, I'm using python3, but also Windows.  I read somewhere that time.sleep(0) waits for 10-13 ms which should be much greater than my limit.  I will nevertheless try 1./250 when I get home

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `requests.get` function is a blocking call. It will wait until the response arrives before the rest of your program will execute. If you want to be able to do other things, you will probably want to look at the [***asyncio***](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) or [***multiprocessing***](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) modules.

Comment: You aren't repeating the request.get inside your loop. So if it fails the first time your program will just loop forever (sleeping in between loops)

Comment: I am in case of error, that part of the code somehow wasn't selected when I copy/pasted it.  Fixed it, thanks

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer because it contains part of the answer I was seeking and the other part of the answer was answered by the API hosts.  Turns out I'm not running into my rate limit, but some variable rate limit set to prevent servers from flooding, as suggested in one of the comments to the question.